# Formatting date time using XSLT

Tags: datetime, xslt

I have a requirement in which I have to format the date value in the incoming request. I am able to extract the value however it is not getting properly formatted.

Below is the Input request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <Invoice Version="3.0">
         <Header>
            <ThisDocumentIdentifier>
               <DocumentIdentifier>0000001007128564</DocumentIdentifier>
            </ThisDocumentIdentifier>
            <ThisDocumentDateTime>
               <DateTime DateTimeQualifier="On">20140429T031659Z</DateTime>
            </ThisDocumentDateTime>
            </Header>
      </Invoice>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The Date value is **20140429T031659Z**

Output needed **2014-04-29T03:16:59Z**

Below is the code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"  xmlns:dp="http://www.datapower.com/extensions">
    <xsl:template match="*[local-name()='DateTime']">
        <xsl:variable name="FormatDatetime">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(., 1, 4), '-', substring(., 5, 2), '-', substring(., 7, 2),substring(.,9,2),':',substring(.,11,2),':',substring(.,13,2),'Z')"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:message dp:priority="debug"> Formatted date= <xsl:value-of select="$FormatDatetime"/>
        </xsl:message>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is the output I am getting
**2014-04-29T0:31:65Z**

For some reason one of the number is getting removed and I am not sure why?

Can anyone please advise where I am doing it wrong?

I have added the 'T' as well.

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(., 1, 4), '-', substring(., 5, 2), '-', substring(., 7, 2),'T',substring(.,9,2),':',substring(.,11,2),':',substring(.,13,2),'Z')"/>
```

Got the output as
**2014-04-29TT0:31:65Z**

This is the updated working code thank to panhandel.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"  xmlns:dp="http://www.datapower.com/extensions">
    <xsl:template match="*[local-name()='DateTime']">
        <xsl:variable name="FormatDatetime">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(., 1, 4), '-', substring(., 5, 2), '-', substring(., 7, 2),substring(.,9,3),':',substring(.,11,2),':',substring(.,13,2),'Z')"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:message dp:priority="debug"> Formatted date= <xsl:value-of select="$FormatDatetime"/>
        </xsl:message>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you shorted the T03 part by one character by using `substring(.,9,2)`.

It should be `substring(.,9,3)`

Comment: Regarding your edit, if there's a requirement to add the T manually, you'll simply want to change the substring(.,9,2) to substring(.,10,2)